# This version of Geodatabase is incompatible with dataset and cannot open it using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, annotation, arcgis-pro-sdk

This implementation is done in ArcGIS Pro .Net SDK and has an Enterprise geodatabase. We had a polyline feature layer and move functionality was implemented in this. The functionality was working fine until we added a linked annotation feature with this polyline feature layer.

Details of error is as below.

> This version of the Geodatabase client is incompatible with the dataset and cannot open it. [dataset name: **********]
>   ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IFeature.Store()
>      at (SourceFeatureClass sourceFeatureClass, IFeature featureAtTargetVersion, IFeature featureAtJobVersion).

Comment: Since the API is complaining about a version, it would probably be useful to [Edit] the question to specify the versions of Pro, the geodatabase, and the underlying database.

Comment: I think you will have to provide more information on versioning type, version(default or not), public/private/protected, version of pro, geodatabase to get a good answer. I had a similar issue and had to do a backup on the database in the end, as it came out that the database was corrupted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the ArcGIS Pro does not support annotations that are generated from ArcMap. Since most of the customers using our product uses their old data we have added another project to handle this. Now the problem is solved.